# RX and Exception Handling

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

I'm using the reactive extensions for a kind of a in process message bus.
The implementation is quite simple.

Register looks like

```
public IDisposable Register<T>(Action<T> action) where T : IMessage
{
   return this.subject
        .OfType<T>()
        .Subscribe(action);
}
```

And send simply:

```
private void SendMessage(IMessage message)
    {
        this.subject.OnNext(message);
    }
```

However i'm now having some trouble with the exception behaviour of RX.
One an exception is thrown in a registered/subscribed action - the Observable 'stream' is broken and will not subscribe anymore.
Sine this message bus is used for two parts of the application to communicate i need to ensure that such a stream is never broken even if an unexpected exception is thrown.

Comment: Note that the default version Subject<T> is not threadsafe. If you are implementing a message bus that can be used across threads you might want to be careful.

Comment: Thank you for this hint.
Is this a problem if all the registrations are done in the main thread in other threads is only the OnNext called?

Comment: Subject.OnNext is not threadsafe. If it is called from multiple threads then you are in trouble. You would need to create a wrapper which locks the subject each time.

Comment: Also subscribe is not threadsafe. Same problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you need to ensure that the stream is never broken by an exception, then you need to have another channel for the exceptions.

This behavior is not completely unexpected.  From the documentation for the [`IObserver<T>` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783449.aspx):

> The OnError method, which is typically called by the provider to indicate that data is unavailable, inaccessible, or corrupted, or that the provider has experienced some other error condition.

Given this, if the stream is unavailable, corrupted, etc, you definitely want the stream to be "faulted" (this is analagous to a channel being faulted in WCF); the state is indeterminate so you can't rely on anything else that comes from the [`IObservable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd990377.aspx) implementation; so why should there be an expectation that there will be any more observations?

That said, you have a some options:

**Swallow the exception**

You'd have to wrap the `action` delegate that you pass into your `Register` function, like so:

```
public IDisposable Register<T>(Action<T> action) where T : IMessage
{
   return this.subject
        .OfType<T>()
        .Subscribe(t => {
            // Execute action
            try { action(t); }
            catch { }
         });
}
```

This, of course, might not be desirable, as you might be throwing away exceptions which impact your program (or, you might know *exactly* what's going on here, and want to skip them), but it can be used to build on the next solution.

**Provide an action to take when an exception is thrown**

Using the above as the base, you can ask for an [`Action<T, Exception>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549311.aspx) which will be called when an exception is thrown.

```
public IDisposable Register<T>(Action<T> action, 
    Action<T, Exception> errorHandler) where T : IMessage
{
   return this.subject
        .OfType<T>()
        .Subscribe(t => {
            // Execute action
            try { action(t); }
            catch (Exception e) { errorHandler(t, e); }
         });
}
```

Now, when an exception is thrown from `action`, it will be passed to your exception handler without breaking the stream.

The above can easily be overloaded to provide the behavior which will swallow the exception (which again, may or may not serve your purposes):

```
public IDisposable Register<T>(Action<T> action) where T : IMessage
{
    // Call the overload, don't do anything on
    // exception.
    return Register(action, (t, e) => { });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your very good answer.
But i have a problem with this behaviour:
In my app bootstrapper this Registrations are done. So when now an exception is thrown anywhere in the app i do not know when to reregister and when not. this is fairly a problem for me... but i need to throw exceptions in the classic manner because otherwise i can not use any try..catch consturct. so the handler action is not really an option for me, because the registering happens somewhere completely else. you see my problem?

Comment: @LaurinSt Then you have a bigger problem on your hands.  Using a `try`/`catch` model is associated with a pull model (something like, `IEnumerable<T>`).  What you have here is a push model.  `try`/`catch` doesn't work in the push model unless you place the exception handler in the handler for the push, as shown above.

Comment: You may find this topic on Advanced error handling from IntroToRx.com useful also: http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/11_AdvancedErrorHandling.html

Comment: @Philippe None of those help in this situation. The question requires the original sequence to continue producing.  All of those solutions require a second sequence which continues to produce.

Answer (score 2):

Basically you can provide an OnError delegate on the Subscribe method. I've written a small tutorial that takes this matter into consideration (Exception Handling), quite recently on my blog : http://blog.andrei.rinea.ro/2013/06/01/bing-it-on-reactive-extensions-story-code-and-slides/

Have look at the OnError method. Basically you need to resubscribe since the Rx framework is built on the premise that a sequence is broken when an error has occured.